# Decomposition of a Matrix by Sparse Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, finite-fields, sparse-matrices

Let $\mathbb{F}$ is a field. Consider an $n \times n$ matrix $\bf A$ over  $\mathbb{F}$.

$\bf A$ is called *sparse matrix* over $\mathbb{F}$ iff the number of non-zero entities of $\bf A$  be at most $2n$.

**My question:**

Consider a non-zero $n \times n$ matrix $\bf M$ over $\mathbb{F}$. Is there a method or an algorithm such that $\bf M$ can be decomposed as follows: 
$$
{\bf M}=\prod_{i=1}^n\, {\bf A}_i=A_1\,A_2\, \cdots \,A_n\, .
$$
where ${\bf A}_i$'s are sparse $n \times n$ matrices over $\mathbb{F}$. (I need binary finite field or $\mathbb{F}_{2^q}$)

For simplicity, we can assume that ${\bf A}_i$'s have the same sparsity pattern.

I appreciate to address me  paper or book about this subject.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Related: https://mathoverflow.net/q/258283/91764

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo The restriction $n$ sparse matrix is important for me. In your answer there is no guarantee for parameter $n$ but your answer is interesting.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Is it possible to ask you to make an example for an $4 \times 4$ matrix over a finite field such as $GF(2^4)$ as an answer in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2848755/decomposition-of-a-matrix-by-sparse-matrices) similar to example that you made in [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/258283/decomposing-a-matrix-into-a-product-of-sparse-matrices). I appreciate and thank you for your support

Comment: Isn't it just Gaussian elimination over a finite field? Consult a table to find the multiplicative inverses.