# Expressing an invertible sparse matrix as a product of few elementary matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, sparse-matrices

Let $M$ be an $n \times n$ matrix with integer entries.  Suppose that $M$ is invertible (over the integers) and that $M$ has at most $An$ nonzero entries, each of which is less than $B$ in absolute value, for some constants $A,B<\infty$.

> Is $M$ necessarily the product of $Cn$ elementary matrices whose single off-diagonal entries are less than $D$ in absolute value, for some constants $C$ and $D$ depending on $A$ and $B$?

A simple Gaussian elimination does not appear to come anywhere close to showing this.  Sparsity is lost rapidly (the number of nonzero entries can grow exponentially in the number of steps in the elimination process), and so there will be order $n^2$ elementary matrices, with off-diagonal entries of order $2^{n^2}$ times $B$ (or something like that).  Perhaps the bound I'm asking for is too optimistic, but are there any significant improvements on the "trivial" Gaussian elimination approach (which doesn't take much advantage of sparsity)?

One could ask the same question over the rationals, where instead of bounding the absolute value of the entries, we bound their height (absolute value of numerator plus absolute value of denominator, when written in lowest terms).  I presume this is more or less equivalent to the problem over the integers (and I would be happy with an answer in either setting).

Comment: A tiny correction: for $M$ to be the product of elementary matrices like you indicate, it has to have determinant $1$ (as opposed to $-1$). You probably already know this, but for $n \geq 3$ the group $\text{SL}_n(\mathbb{Z})$ is bounded generated by elementary matrices, so there is some absolute constant $E$ (whose value is known, I just don't remember what it is right now) such that every element of $\text{SL}_n(\mathbb{Z})$ is a product of at most $E$ elementary matrices. Of course, there is no control over the sizes of the entries in these elementary matrices and this doesn't use sparsity.

Comment: (here is one nice reference for bounded generation, which has references to the original sources: https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0503083)

Comment: [Possibly related](https://mathoverflow.net/q/258283/91764)